# Defining parameters within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to pass a dynamic variable as a command line option while using Jupyter Notebook,

[image: Here is a screenshot of parameters I am passing]

but I'm running into the following problem.

[image: I am encountering this issue]

I tried setting `board_name = argv and board_name = ""` but it is not working as expected.

My goal is to schedule the notebook with a dynamic variable, but I'm not sure what the problem is. Can someone provide guidance on how to properly pass a dynamic variable to a Jupyter Notebook, or suggest an alternative approach to achieving this?

Comment: What do you mean by "schedule a notebook"? Its not clear what technology you are using here.

Comment: I meant jupyter scheduler. Sorry

Comment: Did you try "First"